# How to display down and right arrow images in jQuery Multi Level CSS Menu #2 by dynamicdrive

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

for one of my wordpress theme,  i am using jQuery Multi Level CSS Menu #2- by http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_multi_level_css_menu_2/

But i can not display, the down and right arrow images:

This is how i am calling them:

```
//Specify full URL to down and right arrow images (23 is padding-right to add to top level LIs with drop downs):
var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', 'down.png'], right:['rightarrowclass', 'right.png']}
```

The arrow images and jqueryslidemenu.js are in same folder.

with full url its working for example like: `http://www.mysite.com/images/down.png`

but i want to call the arrow images from the folder.

Can some one please sort this out for me, how shall call them?

I will really appreciate you help!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is the `.html` in the same folder?

`images/down.png` or `/images/down.png` should work